# Does Batch IF statement handles only one action at a time?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, counter

I am new to batch scripting but drawing from my experience with Bash trying to make sense of things. I am errorlevel checking and if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0, I wanted it to echo a message and then increment a counter variable, ELSE echo another message and EXIT with an exit code.

Example of what I have done:

```
@echo off
SET counter=0

dir /a
SET RC=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %RC% == 0 ECHO [INFO] - Command executed successfully. SET /A counter=counter+1 ELSE ECHO [ERROR] - Something went wrong here EXIT /B 99
```

The above example did not work as I expected. The IF-ELSE statement is on a single line and the output I got was

> Command executed successfully. SET /A counter=counter+1

When I enclosed the echo and set commands in (), it complains that

> (set was unexpected at this time

So, how can I ON TRUE echos a message and increment counter by 1; and on false quit the script with a certain %ERRORLEVEL% code?

Comment: I would like to note that I could just do a IF %RC% == 0 (SET /A counter=counter+1) ELSE (echo There was an error in last command).

Comment: It is to mention that the (code blcok in parentheses) does require [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) if a variable is set  and referenced inside the block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
@echo off
SET counter=0

dir /a
SET RC=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %RC% == 0 (ECHO [INFO] - Command executed successfully. & (SET /A counter=counter+1)) ELSE (ECHO [ERROR] - Something went wrong here & (EXIT /B 99))
```

`Counter`, if executed successfully will have the value of one. Also, using  `dir /a` requires an attribute after `/a` such as `/a:h` for hidden files. Do `dir /?` for more attributes.

Comment: Actually, `/a` does not require an attribute. I forget for the moment quite what it yields - all entries, perhaps - but it's actually valid (although rarely encountered)

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work just fine and it's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle various actions putting these actions in  a code block `()`.

You can Use the conditional `&&` and `||` operators :

```
dir /a && (
    echo success
    SET /A counter+=1
    ) || echo failed
```

or :

```
IF %RC%==0 (
   ECHO [INFO] - Command executed successfully. 
   SET /A counter=counter+1
   ) ELSE (
   ECHO [ERROR] - Something went wrong here 
   EXIT /B 9
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe I have tried this and running this from within SSIS calling the batch script, it returned a 255 exit code. :(

Comment: Check both solutions !

Comment: Thank you for this. I have implemented code block with the correct syntax as @jangles put forward below. Much better!